# Blogger next previous navigations missing

Tags: button, navigation, themes, blogger, posts

I am trying to add next and previous posts to the free theme in blogger, I can see the buttons using css but they are unresponsive. I have used a lot of codes available online but none of them are working.

Can someone help what else i need to do?